# Owl carusel work incorrect

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I try fix owl carousel, button "next" and "prev" working odd way. When i click "prev", carousel don't back to a slide that had been here before click. I think something wrong order sequence slides.
And i don't know how to terminate  what a script launch when clicked some button.

Comment: Show us code, and show us what you tried, please dont post only text related things only

Comment: If u provide tried code here,it will be helped to others to help you

Answer (score 0):

If you init owl like ('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({attributes});
It must work correct, but will be better if you show us your code.
Please check console logs to determine errors.